# ForeignKey to a model that is defined after/below the current model

Tags: django

Having the error msg

```
order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
NameError: name 'Order' is not defined
```

So how ever I do one class will be missing cuz of the class is below the currently reading class so that the class is missing. How do I solve this? i've read about many-to-many function, might that solve the problem?

```
class Items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

class OrderedItem(models.Model):
    items = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.items

class Order(models.Model):
    #clientID
    orderedItem = models.ForeignKey(OrderedItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #truckId Foreign key till truck
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    emergency = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    #building
    #floor
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Comment: Have you tried `order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`?

Comment: @ShangWang Yeah, but the problem is that Order dosn't exist yet. I hasnt been created when It's looking for the Order class.

Comment: Note that I added the quotes around the `Order`.

Comment: @ShangWang when I change to quotes I get a error msg Reverse query name for 'Order.orderedItems' clashes with field name 'OrderedItem.order' HINT Rename field 'OrderedItem.order'

Comment: I didn't mean to change anything for you, but I can't help but wondering why you have `orderItem` as foreignkey in `Order`? What's the use case?

Comment: So that a person can place serveral orders with diffirent order names.

Comment: But that does *not* enable that. You should remove that FK.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Use the fully-qualified model string

When this happens, I usually resort to what's called the *fully-qualified model string*, fancy term for what's essential a string representing the model and the containing app in the format of `'app_label.ModelName'`

E.g. if your model is `Order`, then the model string name would be the string `'Order'`

So you can already do:

```
order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

With the above, Django will look for the model `'Order'` in the same app. It's okay if you have not defined it yet, as long as it is defined.

If that model happens to come from a different app, it would be:

```
order = models.ForeignKey('appname.Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

### Reverse query clashes

Because `Order` points to `OrderItems` and `OrderItems` point to `Order` you get a clash with [related queries that Django generate for you. You can disable those with `related_name='+'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
```

### Better modeling

Since a `OrderedItem` already "belongs" to an `Order`, there's no point in having a ForeignKey from `Order` to `OrderedItem`, you can just remove it instead of dealing with the above clash.

So what you'd have would look like this

```
Item

Order

OrderedItem
    + FK(Item)
    + FK(Order)
```

A design which wouldn't involve referencing a model that hasn't been defined yet :)

Comment: Alright, when I change to quotes I get a error msg Reverse query name for 'Order.orderedItems' clashes with field name 'OrderedItem.order'

Comment: Added a section to explain the clash

Comment: I think the second FK is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of relationships; I don't think OP needs to change the related_name, or convert to M2M, they need to *remove* it.

Comment: Agree, added a suggested DB model that avoids the conundrum in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it can't find the class order is because it hasn't been defined yet, you either need to specify it as a string as shown by Shang Wang, or change the order of them in your models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    #clientID
    orderedItem = models.ForeignKey(OrderedItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #truckId Foreign key till truck
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    emergency = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    #building
    #floor
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id    

class OrderedItem(models.Model):
    items = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.items
```

Changing the order has its advantages over specifying as a string since it will allow IDE's to find usages of the class should it ever need refactoring.

---

Since you have foreign keys to both classes, the above won't work and only applies to one-to-one or one-to-many relationships. Instead, it would be better to define a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) instead of the two foreign keys

Comment: I don't mean to bother you, but doesn't this pose a problem because we're using `OrderedItem` (as a model ref not string), before it was defined? (looks like it would result in same issue as before no?

Answer (score -1):

You have defined `class Items` before use it and you have not any error.
you must define  `class Order` before `class OrderedItem`.