# Define ForeignKey to a model before defining that model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

So I am in a situation where I need to create a foreign key to a model before that model is defined. Consider the following models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    """Model for question."""

    question_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.PROTECT)  # Can't do this


class Option(models.Model):
    """Model for options of a question."""

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=127)
```

So as you can see, I have a model to save a Question(text and its answer). Also I have another model to save one option which is linked to a question. That way I can create variable number to options for a question, one of which will be correct. But I can't link the correct option to the model `Question` because the model `Question` needs to be declared first to link each `Option` to a `Question`.
Is there some way I can achieve this.

#### Update

After thinking a bit I figured out the model structure I can use, I need one more model for answers.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    """Model for question."""
    ...


class Option(models.Model):
    """Model for options of a question."""
    ...

class Answer(models.Model):
    """Model for answers."""

    question = models.OneToOneField(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

But the question still remains how I can reference a model before defining it(if it's even possible).

Comment: Check out [django-modelcluster](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster).

Comment: good package, but it's for a slightly different purpose.

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459326/foreignkey-to-a-model-that-is-defined-after-below-the-current-model/35459441 is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would rewrite your code example:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    """Model for question."""

    question_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    answer = models.ForeignKey('Option', on_delete=models.PROTECT)  # Can't do this


class Option(models.Model):
    """Model for options of a question."""

    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=127)
```

Please pay attention to the first argument (in bold) passed to `ForeignKey`. It is a string with the name of the model.

If you check the official Django documentation for [foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) you'll see that this is explained there:

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself

Personally I regard this is a good practice and use it consistently throughout all   model classes, regardless of the order in which they are defined. The benefit is that when you refactor your code you don't have to think of the order.

Furthermore you can refer to models from other apps:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey('baz.SomeModel', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

without explicitly importing the module like:

```
from baz.models import SomeModel
```

Comment: Bro you are a lifesaver , such a simple solution and I was going crazy trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Glad that it helped. I forgot to mention that it is called `lazy relationship`, in case you want to refer back to this issue.